# LLTV Systems breakdown(2)

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, impulse-response, laplace-transform

In [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87553/lltv-systems-linearity-breakdown?noredirect=1#comment186560_87553) I proved that for a linear linearly time varying system $S$ such that if $t_{2} = t_{1}+t_{0}$ then $h(t,t_{2}) = h(t,t_{1})+h(t,t_{0})\rightarrow$ $h(t,t_{0}) = g(t_{0})h(t) $ where $g(t)$ is a linear function $(At+B)$.

But now since we have values for $t_{2},t_{1},t_{0},g(t_{2}),g(t_{1}),g(t_{0})$ we can figure out exactly $A$ and $B$.$A = \frac{g(t_{1})-g(t_{0})}{t_{1}-t_{0}}$ and we can find $B$ by putting the condition $g(t_{2}) = \frac{g(t_{1})-g(t_{0})}{t_{1}-t_{0}}t_{2}+B$.

And now since we have the complete expression of how $h(t)$ changes over time (its $g(t)h(t)$) we can do the convolution in the Laplace domain find the function by doing the convolution then be able to describe the transfer function $H(s)$ over s and how the poles and zeros change over s.Is that correct?

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. You've not "proved" anything in the linked question, you're only asking. Your writing is also very hard to follow and overly compressed. Please show your thinking more clearly and write some steps.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I checked my thoughts explained in the linked question and I don't find anything wrong. Also I am doing some research on time varying systems so I may be out of the literature and maybe instead of posting this comment take your time and have a look at the question and the linked question, maybe you can spot any mistakes I have made.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon also my line of thinking in both this and the linked question are quite clearly, I honestly don't understand what you are talking about...

Comment: I mean this constructively. It's clear to you, not to everyone. You've worked on it for a while. A part of asking a good question is lowering the work needed for others to understand. I'm not saying it's impossible to understand, but that many of us won't bother. You're asking for our time, it's fair to return the favor.